# custom post type with metabox custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

how to make meta custom fields in custom post type name jobs_board_cpt , I am using boilerplate ?

```
public function jobs_board_cpt() {

        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'All Jobs', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentyfive' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Job Board', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentyfive' ),
            'menu_name'             => __( 'Jobs Board', 'twentyfive' ),
            'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Jobs Board', 'twentyfive' ),
            'archives'              => __( 'Jobs Board Archives', 'twentyfive' ),
            'attributes'            => __( 'Jobs Board Attributes', 'twentyfive' ),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Job Board:', 'twentyfive' ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Jobs', 'twentyfive' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Job', 'twentyfive' ),
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Job', 'twentyfive' ),
            'new_item'              => __( 'New Job ', 'twentyfive' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Job', 'twentyfive' ),
            'update_item'           => __( 'Update Job', 'twentyfive' ),
            'view_item'             => __( 'View Job', 'twentyfive' ),
            'view_items'            => __( 'View Jobs', 'twentyfive' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search Jobs', 'twentyfive' ),
            'not_found'             => __( 'Jobs Not found', 'twentyfive' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Jobs Not found in Trash', 'twentyfive' ),
            'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image Jobs Board', 'twentyfive' ),
            'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured Job image', 'twentyfive' ),
            'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image Job ', 'twentyfive' ),
            'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image Jobs Board', 'twentyfive' ),
            'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Jobs Board', 'twentyfive' ),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Jobs Board', 'twentyfive' ),
            'items_list'            => __( 'Jobs list', 'twentyfive' ),
            'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Jobs list navigation', 'twentyfive' ),
            'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Jobs list', 'twentyfive' ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'label'                 => __( 'Job Board', 'twentyfive' ),
            'description'           => __( 'This is Jobs Board custom type', 'twentyfive' ),
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor','custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'post-formats' ),
            //'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
            'hierarchical'          => false,
            'public'                => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => true,
            'menu_position'         => 5,
            'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-shortcode',
            'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
            'can_export'            => true,
            'has_archive'           => true,
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'capability_type'       => 'post',
            'show_in_rest'          => true,
        );
        register_post_type( 'jobs_board_cpt', $args );
    }
        
    
     // Add meta boxes for jobs_board custom post type
//add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_jobs_board_meta_boxes');
public function add_jobs_board_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box(
        'job_salary_meta_box',
        'Salary',
        'render_job_salary_meta_box',
        'jobs_board_cpt',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );

    add_meta_box(
        'job_location_meta_box',
        'Location',
        'render_job_location_meta_box',
        'jobs_board_cpt',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}

// Render job salary meta box
public function render_job_salary_meta_box($post) {
    $salary = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'job_salary', true);
    ?>
    <label for="job_salary">Salary:</label>
    <input type="text" id="job_salary" name="job_salary" value="<?php echo esc_attr($salary); ?>">
    <?php
}

// Render job location meta box
public function render_job_location_meta_box($post) {
    $location = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'job_location', true);
    ?>
    <label for="job_location">Location:</label>
    <input type="text" id="job_location" name="job_location" value="<?php echo esc_attr($location); ?>">
    <?php
}

// Save job board meta data
//add_action('save_post', 'save_jobs_board_meta_data');
public function save_jobs_board_meta_data($post_id) {
    // Check if nonce is set
    if (!isset($_POST['nonce_field'])) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce_field'], 'nonce_action')) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if this is an autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if user has permissions to save data
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return;
    }

    // Save meta data for salary
    if (isset($_POST['job_salary'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'job_salary', sanitize_text_field($_POST['job_salary']));
    }

    // Save meta data for location
    if (isset($_POST['job_location'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'job_location', sanitize_text_field($_POST['job_location']));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?